# Exception when applying ClaimsPrincipalPermissionAttribute at both class level and method level

Tags: c#, .net, wif, claims-based-identity, code-access-security

I have a class which is decorated with a `ClaimsPrincipalPermissionsAttribute`. The class has a method that is also decorated with a `ClaimsPrincipalPermissionsAttribute`. What I expected was:

First, when I instantiate the class, I get a call to my custom `ClaimsAuthorizationManager`. This works as expected.

Second, when I call the method, I get two calls to my `ClaimsAuthorizationManager`. One with the Resource and Operation from the class level attribute and one from the method level attribute. This does not work. Instead, I get a `SecurityException` thrown when I call the method. The exception message is:

> Failure decoding embedded permission set object.

To try to see what was happening, I created a custom attribute by copying the code from `ClaimsPrincipalPermissionsAttribute`. I can see that `CreatePermission()` method is called on my attribute and it returns a ClaimsPrincipalPermission successfully, but the exception is thrown before my `ClaimsAuthorizationManager` is called.

My code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Services;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new SecuredClass();

            test.MethodLevelSecuredMethod();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    [ClaimsPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Resource = "SecuredClass", Operation = "GeneralAccess")]
    class SecuredClass
    {
        [ClaimsPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Resource = "MethodLevelSecuredMethod", Operation = "Call")]
        public void MethodLevelSecuredMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Called MethodLevelSecuredMethod");
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to declare the attribute at both the class and method level?

I am using .Net 4.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is occurring because `ClaimsPrincipalPermission` does not implement a public constructor that takes a `PermissionState` argument.  (The need for this is documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yaah0wb2.aspx, albeit hidden in the middle of the text.)

This is essentially a bug in the framework, which should probably be reported at https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/feedback.  If you do so, you might want to add that an FxCop rule to check for the presence of this constructor might be a good idea as well.

Pending a bug fix, your only real option is to re-implement both `ClaimsPrincipalPermission` and `ClaimsPrincipalPermissionAttribute` if you want to use a declarative approach for claims-based authorization.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by using a `CheckAccess` call within the class constructor:

```
class SecuredClass
{
    public SecuredClass()
    {
        ClaimsPrincipalPermission.CheckAccess("SecuredClass", "GeneralAccess");
    }

    [ClaimsPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Resource = "MethodLevelSecuredMethod", Operation = "Call")]
    public void MethodLevelSecuredMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called MethodLevelSecuredMethod");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this workaround, and came into additional issues.  When the above CheckAccess method was called and returned false - a System.Security.SecurityException was thrown however before I could catch a System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was thrown in System.IdentityModel.Services (mscorlib.dll) As a result this made it difficult to catch the security exception as it was wrapped by the targetinvocationexception